# GIT Push changes from client to locally created GIT server

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have cloned a repo from remote to my VM(lets say **A**).I am making **A** as my GIT server locally.
I have other client VM's(lets say **B,C,etc**).
From **B** i am cloning from **A** which happened successfully.
Now if i make some change in **B** how do i push my changes to **A** or the vice versa.
NOTE : I am currently not looking to push it to remote repo.
I just want to push or pull from my client VM's(**B,C**) to locally created GIT server i.e., **A**

It's a linux environment.

Comment: Are you speaking about setting a different remote for your project?

Comment: Yes A is a local remote for me.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the manifest from A to one of the linux server B or C.
Now go inside manifest and modify the default.xml --> under remote tag
fetch and review.
Fetch : the url from where you want to fetch the code.
Review : the url to which you want to push the code.
Better to make Fetch and review point to the git server A.
Now do a git commit and git push the default.xml changes.